# Index Match across 2 sheets not working

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am trying the following function but it is not working:

=INDEX(Accounts!$A$2:$AB$2820,MATCH($A$2,Accounts!$E$2:$E$2820,0),6)

I get a #N/A result

Both sheets are in the same workbook.

Accounts has the Account Name (Column E) and Account ID (Column F)

Current Sheet (Customers) has the Account Name (Column A) but not Account ID.

I am trying to match the Account Names in the current sheet to the Account Names in the Account Sheet and then pull in the Account ID.

Hope that makes sense. Have spent hours trying to make this work. Please help!

Comment: @pnuts, it's the column number in `index(range, row, column)`

Comment: Your formula is correct. There's a reason in your data that makes it fail to find a match. More information is needed about the data. Check for extra spaces in the names, for example.

Comment: Try sorting the lookup column(E on Accounts) and using 1 instead of 0 in the third criterion of the match.  If you get a return start looking at the data to find out why it does not find a match.  Remember `0` indicates an exact match.

Comment: @ScottCraner Caution with that advice about 1 as the third parameter of Match. If people don't understand the concept of the approximate match, they may fall victim to unintentional approximate matches, which may NOT be what they want, and may lead to totally wrong results in their spreadsheets. Approximate match may be the solution, but #N/A may be valid, too. It REALLY depends on the context.

Comment: @teylyn I was trying to show that the problem was not the formula but the data, hence the ` If you get a return start looking at the data to find out why it does not find a match.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your responses. I looked into the formula further and discovered two reasons why it wasn't working:

1. The first item did not have a match causing #N/A
2. The formula kept looking at that first result for all subsequent rows.

Original Formula:
=INDEX(Accounts!$A$2:$AB$2820,MATCH(**$A$2**,Accounts!$E$2:$E$2820,0),6)

Correct Formula:
=INDEX(Accounts!$A$2:$AB$2820,MATCH(**A2**,Accounts!$E$2:$E$2820,0),6)

When you pull down the original formula onto subsequent rows it stays exactly the same. When you pull down the correct formula the values for the lookup updates correctly.

Answer (score -3):

index needs to be 1 column, and get rid of the 6

```
=INDEX(Accounts!$A$2:$A$2820,MATCH($A$2,Accounts!$E$2:$E$2820,0))
```

the index is the column you want your result from, in this case column A on accounts sheet, the match is the column that has the criteria you are loooking for in this case column E on Accounts sheet

if this still return an NA then you are not making a match with your value, check to make sure the column that you are matching has the same value, even a space can make it return an NA

Comment: No, INDEX does not need to be one column. You *can* index into a bidimensional array.

Comment: @user3005775 Maybe you should go and learn a bit more about Excel yourself. In the [documentation for Index](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) you will find that the array version of the function can handle a third parameter, in fact, that third parameter is required in a multi-row, multi-column range.

Comment: and this is what you get for trying to help people

Comment: Nobody doubts your intention, but you may want to work on the delivery.

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question or resolve the problem and gives errant information, also with the 6 at the end the OP is looking to return column F not A.  Only the MATCH part of the equation needs to be a single column or row,  Not the INDEX

Comment: @teylyn is the third really required in a two dimensional array?  I thought it defaulted to 0 and returned the whole column if left empty.  Is that assumption wrong?

Comment: @ScottCraner if Index references a one-column or a one-row range, you don't need a third parameter, of course. But the OP posted a formula that references a multi-column, multi-row array, so the third parameter is required to locate the column. Unfortunately, user3005775 changed the context by providing a formula that references a two-dimensional range, and then claims that the problem is with the third parameter. It's all a bit of a mess, really. So, going back to the Op's question and their `#N/A`: it's not about the third parameter, but about the first Match returning an error.